# Nvidia GPU is not workin on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, pantheon

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 with pantheon desktop, I installed the Nvidia drivers with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

After the process was completed I restarted my pc. 
Now the NVIDIA X Servers Settings are installed and the app center shows the driver was successfully installed, but when I try to change the main GPU with prime settings, it doesn't work.
[Prime settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsyCr.png)
[Additional drivers settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCLRT.png)

I ran the following command to figure out what GPU is really working. This is what I get:

```
$ glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
```

I don't know if I have followed any wrong procedure.
Thanks for your help!

Computer specs:

CPU : Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz

GPU: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX130] (rev a2)

Edit: This is what I get from running the following command.

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] UHD Graphics 620
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX130] (rev a2)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GM108M [GeForce MX130]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

And this one:

```
$ mokutil --sb-state 
SecureBoot disabled
```

Edit: I am going to write down some terminal commands  that are shown in comments.

```
$ env |grep GDMSESSION
GDMSESSION=pantheon
```

And this one:

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: It is disabled.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: And also `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: Nvidia X server settings is empty. that means that the driver is not installed properly.

Comment: Try to install official drivers, not from a PPA. All looks good now except the X sever window.

Comment: Fine, I'll delete the PPA and try again. Thanks!

Comment: Have you run `prime-select query` to see what video you are on?  If it says `intel` run `prime-select nvidia` and then reboot.

Comment: I have removed the PPA and installed the driver directly from the app center, still have the same problem

Comment: @Terrance this is what I get
`$ prime-select query`
`nvidia`

Comment: Have you rebooted since the installation?  Unfortunately, it does not automatically switch to NVIDIA / Intel on the fly.  Each change requires a reboot to activate the driver.

Comment: Yes, I rebooted my pc, but still have the same problem, NVIDIA settings shows like the Nvidia GPU is activated, but is not.

Comment: First make sure you're not using wayland session. (`env |grep GDMSESSION`  should show.) If not then maybe try switching to Intel ( `sudo prime-select intel` ) and reboot. Then try switching to nvidia and reboot.

Comment: At your login, did you select any option with "Wayland" init?  That switches to the Intel drivers (in 18.04).  19.10 wont even offer a Wayland choice if Nvidia drivers are installed.

Comment: @doug 
@ubfan1
I'm using pantheon
`$ env |grep GDMSESSION` shows this: `GDMSESSION=pantheon`

Comment: I think they asked for the wrong output.  What is the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: @Terrance `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` shows `x11`

Comment: Hmmmm, that is definitely correct.  I don't have a system like what you have so I would be no more help beyond here.  I will add another upvote so hopefully we can get more eyes on this question.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was fixed with an update.

Yesterday I changed to the Nvidia GPU (just for curiosity) and then I rebooted my PC. Now it is working as it used! Since I have not changed anything I assume an update fixed this.